# Помогите удалить все нечетные цифры в двухмерном массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы

````
    [5, 8, 3, 2, 7 ],
    [77, 40, 55, 20, 99],
    [999, 400, 555, 800, 777],
];```
````

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. **Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.**

Answer (score 3):

Наверное ты имела ввиду числа, а не цифры. Тогда можно использовать такие решения:

Можно убрать нечетные числа из старого двухмерного массива:

```
arr = [[5, 8, 3, 2, 7 ],
    [77, 40, 55, 20, 99],
    [999, 400, 555, 800, 777],
];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].filter(function (n) { return n % 2 === 0 })
}
console.log(arr);
```

Можно создать новый двухмерный массив без нечетных чисел не меняя исходный:

```
arr = [[5, 8, 3, 2, 7 ],
    [77, 40, 55, 20, 99],
    [999, 400, 555, 800, 777],
];
let ans = [];
for (line of arr) {
    ans.push(line.filter(function (n) { return n % 2 === 0 }));
}
console.log(ans);
```

И всё таки, если ты говорила про цифры, то условие `n % 2 === 0`
надо заменить на `n % 2 === 0 && 0 <= n && n <= 9`